# Select 1 row from main table and multiple rows from related table

Tags: php, mysql, relation

I have a mysql "users" table with:

```
id | name
1  | Jane Doe
```

and a second table "custom_user_fields" (related with userid):

```
id | userid | fieldname | value
1  | 1      | country   | us
2  | 1      | address   | test address
```

With PHP I have to create a list with all users and its related fields (if possibile with one single query).

Expected result:

```
id | name     | country | address
1  | Jane Doe | us      | test address
```

It's possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible for a pre-defined set of related fields in table `custom_user_fields`. You can use *conditional aggregation*:

```sql
SELECT u.id, u.name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN fieldname = 'country' THEN value END) AS country, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN fieldname = 'address' THEN value END) AS address
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN custom_user_fields AS c ON u.id = c.userid 
GROUP BY u.id, u.name
```